# Links don't function or show hover effects

Tags: html, css, firefox

I'm working on a website and my navigation bar, which I made using a table (yes, I know, a table...). It suddenly stopped using hover and I can't even click on links.

If you remove the code from `img.top` until `img.absB` the nav bar will work fine. But that distorts my images, which have been positioned specifically.

(using FireFox 37)

```css
body {
  background-color: #444657;
}
#table1 {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  height: 40px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
#table1 th {
  border: 1px solid #D3D3D3;
  padding: 3px 7px 2px 7px;
  background-color: #D3D3D3;
  text-align: center;
  /*border-radius:10px;
    -moz-border-radius:10px;
    -webkit-border-radius:10px;
    */
}
#table1 th:hover {
  background-color: #8AC007;
  border: 1px solid #8AC007;
}
#table1 th a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
#table1 th a:link {
  color: #000000;
}
#table1 th a:visited {
  color: #000000;
}
#table1 th a:active {
  color: #000000;
}
img.top {
  position: absolute;
  top: -120px;
  right: 200px;
}
img.absL {
  position: absolute;
  top: -120px;
  right: 400px;
}
.absR {
  position: absolute;
  top: -120px;
  left: 390px;
}
img.absT {
  position: absolute;
  top: -300px;
  right: 205px;
}
img.absB {
  position: absolute;
  top: 80px;
  right: 205px;
}
```

```html
<table id="table1">
  <tr>
    <th><a href="http://www.website" target="_blank">someth</a>
    </th>
    <th><a href="http://website" target="_blank">someth</a>
    </th>
    <th><a href="http://website" target="_blank">someth</a>
    </th>
    <th><a href="http://website" target="_blank">someth</a>
    </th>
    <th><a href="http://website" target="_blank">someth</a>
    </th>
    <th><a href="http:/website" target="_blank">someth</a>
    </th>
    <th><a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">GOOGLE</a>
    </th>
  </tr>
</table>

<div>
  <img class="top" src="website1.PNG" />
  <img class="absL" src="website_Left.png" />
  <img class="absR" src="website_Right.PNG" />
  <img class="absT" src="website_TOP.PNG" />
  <img class="absB" src="website_Bottom.PNG" />
</div>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can post the html.  Otherwise, this will be difficult to debug (my guess is impossible, and you mistake lies in what you can't post).

Comment: This won't work. Come up with a way to show the HTML, something that displays the same problem, anything. Otherwise, what do you want us to say?

Comment: Without html we're shooting in the dark, but hows about trying z-index -1 on all of the imgs?

Comment: `href="http://website target="_blank"` is that a typo or did you actually miss the `"` to close the href?

Comment: just a typo, not the problem, What i feel the problem is, is how i defined the class and tag identifiers in my CSS styling and how do i refer to them

Comment: your images's top is negative in come cases with an absolute positioning - this would render them off-screen making them not visible... is that on purpose?

Comment: If one of the images is very large, it will overlap everything else, including the table. Is that what could happen?

Comment: That was my first thought. It's the case in most "my linkses aren't working" questions.

Comment: you are absolute positioning the images, without specifying a relative container, so your `<body>` will act as container, meaning that you're images on top of the links, thats why the hover or clicks not working